# Certificate and profile for a mac app for installation on tester PCs

Tags: macos, xamarin

Things have been changing in the Mac Appstore.
As at 10.15.5, all apps, regardless of distribution via AppStore
or outside the AppStore, will need to be notarised. I dont
believe that's true of apps that are shared with your testers
via a profile that specifically lists their device.

I'm struggling to get the right combination of cert type and profile to
be able to distribute my app to my testers to run on their machines.

I have a company and that company has an apple account "Acme Widgets" and
the account holder is "admin@acmewidgets.com".

I have a personal apple dev account too, and I've added myself into the company as an admin.
So when I login to developer.apple.com as myself, I can switch between my
person account "Paul XYZ" and my company account "Acme Widgets".

I have an app developed using Xamarin (visual studio) with a Mac and iOS versions.

I can create a Debug and release versions of my iOS app, no problem. Upload it to the App Store and testers can get it with TestFlight.

Its the mac side that is causing problems...

I can create a Debug version of the mac app, and leave it unsigned.
Or I can sign it with a company developer ID and a profile that includes my Mac.
These run on my mac fine.

But release is causing problems. I want to create a release build that I can
share with my small set of testers. Therefore I think I need to use
the company "developer ID certificate", and a "MacOS development profile" that includes
their devices. But that wont run - I just get code signing errors.

I'm missing something obvious.

Can someone point me towards the type of cert (personal, personal in team or
team/company), and the type of profile I need to share a release version
with my testers?

Many thanks.
Paul

Comment: What is you code signing errors exactly says?

Comment: Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1

Comment: 1) Delete all your provisioning profiles in your Apple developer account and mac

2) Rebuild and archive your app